# Missing return statement in for-loop

Tags: java

I'm trying to find out if a number is a prime number or not. I created this method, which I will be using in another class later.

When compiling it tells me that I need a return statement outside the for-loop, but if I try to return the boolean value it gives me an error (cannot find symbol). What shall I return?

```
public class NumeroPrimo {
    public static boolean primo(int numero){
        for (int i=2; i<numero/2; i++){
            if(numero%i==0){
                return false;
            }
            else return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your method returns either `true` or `false` during the first loop cycle. So the loop is never executed more than once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the loop was not done (numero 1), no return would happen.
Also you return true too often.

```
public static boolean primo(int numero) {
    for (int i = 2; i <= numero/2; i++) {
        if (numero % i == 0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Also for 4 `<=` is required.

Comment: Oh, got it. Basically It tried every number anyway, even if it already returned false, right? Can I add "break" after the first return, to end the cycle as soon as it finds out that it's not prime?

Comment: Originally 9 would encounter that it is not divisible by 2 and return true.

Comment: Wait, but this way the output is always true

Comment: No on the first %i == 0, something dividable, it would return false. All divisions %, must have a remainder.

Comment: Ohh, got it. Thanks!